# Creating a "First run" notification in bash?

Tags: bash

What is the best way to make a "First run" notification in a bash script?
I tried putting `export FIRSTRUN="no"` first,
and later on put

```
`if [ -z "$FIRSTRUN" ]; then
echo "It seems that this may be your first time running this script.";
echo "Please ${GREEN}test whether the needed components are installed${RESET}.";
echo "";
fi`
```

but it simply does it on every time the script is run. If i put the `export FIRSTRUN="no"` after the **if** part, it never runs the **if** part of the code. So that doesn't work.
*I am new at this so please help :D*

Comment: Set the flag inside the if block. Right before the `fi`.

Comment: Usually, you look for the presence of one or more files that will otherwise be created on the first run.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the parent shell state from within your script, so attempting to export a variable will not work.

You could use a config file to store a variable which determines whether the script has been run already:

```
#!/bin/bash

# load vars from config at the start of the script
if [[ -f ~/.your_script.conf ]]; then
  . ~/.your_script.conf
fi

# check whether var has been set to determine first run
if [[ -z $has_run ]]; then
  echo 'first run'

  # set variable in config file for next time
  echo 'has_run=1' >> ~/.your_script.conf
fi
```

Alternatively, if this is the only "config" you have, you could just create a file after the first run and check for its existence to determine whether the script has been run.

Answer (score 0):

The first run of the script should leave behind some sort of *permanent* evidence that it has run; it can then look for that file on startup.

```
do_init () {
   # initialize whatever needs initializing
   touch ~/.alreadyran
}

if ! [ -f ~/.alreadyran ]; then
    echo "First time running."
    do_init
fi
```

If the initialization isn't per-user, it will need to leave the file in a more public place, such as somewhere under `/var`.